# Hiding html tags/content based on screen size

Tags: javascript, css, twitter-bootstrap-3, seo, accessibility

I'm working on a job where my employer wants a responsive website using Bootstrap 3 but they dont want anything visually changed on their existing desktop site (obviously not ideal but out of my control). At the moment I'm working on the footer section. On screens less than 768px wide the desired approach is to have the links within accordions (which I'm using the Bootstrap 3 accordions) but on screens wider than 768px the accordions are abandoned and the groups of links are arranged inline.

https://codepen.io/v_for_vinsanity/pen/mWGRyw/

The issue that I am running into is that on screens <768px the link group headers should only be plain text but on screens >768px the headers need to be wrapped in  tags to drive the accordion functionality. Is it alright to have duplicate headers and using CSS hide/show one version on some screen sizes and vice versa on others?

Example:

```
<h4 class="panel-title">
    <a role="button" class="hidden-md hidden-lg" data-toggle="collapse" data-parent="#accordion" href="#collapseOne" aria-expanded="true" aria-controls="collapseOne" data-href-mobile="#collapseOne" data-href-desktop="#">
        <span class="fa fa-plus visible-xs-inline"></span> <strong>Michigan Health Plans</strong>
    </a>
    <span class="hidden-xs hidden-sm"><strong>Michigan Health Plans</strong></span>
</h4>
```

Will this be an SEO/accessibility issue?

Ive tried to find a way to add/remove tags and content using javascript/jQuery but I havent found a good solution thus far. Any help with this issue is greatly appreciated!

Comment: You are right about SEO, "double content"/"display:none" effects Google ranking. I am not sure about how deadly it is to use it but if you want a website with perfect SEO you shouldn't use it.. You can read something about that here: http://seoshrugged.com/2015/11/30/does-google-crawl-css-displaynone-content/
(src: http://stackoverflow.com/a/29551024/7703846) If you want to use media querys to dynamicly generate the html, its more seo friendly, maybe this helps you:
http://stackoverflow.com/a/22708436/7703846

Answer (score 0):

I think there are no SEO issue, you just need to use breakpoint media query of the version of bootstrap you are using. For example I' using bootstrap version 3 so I use the following:

```
<style type="text/css">
/*==================================================
          Bootstrap 3 Media Queries
==================================================*/

    /*==========  Mobile First Method  ==========*/

    /* Custom, iPhone Retina */ 
    @media only screen and (min-width : 320px) {
      /* YOUR CODE HERE|EXAMPLE CODES*/
       body{
        background-color: red;
       }
    }

    /* Extra Small Devices, Phones */ 
    @media only screen and (min-width : 480px) {
        /* YOUR CODE HERE|EXAMPLE CODES*/
       body{
        background-color: black;
       }

    }

    /* Small Devices, Tablets */
    @media only screen and (min-width : 768px) {
        /* YOUR CODE HERE|EXAMPLE CODES*/
       body{
        background-color: blue;
       }
    }

    /* Medium Devices, Desktops */
    @media only screen and (min-width : 992px) {
         /* YOUR CODE HERE|EXAMPLE CODES| SET HERE WHAT YOU NEED TO HIDE OR ANYTHING*/
       body{
        background-color: green;
       }
    }

    /* Large Devices, Wide Screens */
    @media only screen and (min-width : 1200px) {
        /* YOUR CODE HERE*/
    }
</style>
```

Comment: Thanks for the response but after talking to a number of SEO friends my initial approach would result in SEO issues. Mainly because I  duplicate content effects Google ranking. Again, thanks for the response though!